# where is Apache HttpClient javadoc available

Tags: java, httpclient

where is Apache HttpClient javadoc 4.3.1 available ?
I've seen similar questions where the answer is to web resource, but it is really useful to have instant info eg  in Netbeans

Comment: The source and javadoc at [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before posting, please exhaust other resources such as Google.  Also please read the [FAQ] and [Ask]

Comment: RE Off Topic: The answer chosen identifies that the Javadoc was actually missing from the latest download for what ever reason. It was not to ask for a tool as I stated I had already found it. The aim was to find out why I could not locate it to use as a local resource

Comment: To provide a correct answer to those that stumble across this thread, the docs for 4.3.x are actually on the Apache server.  There is no link for them on any of their pages.  The page for HttpClient is http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/.

Comment: I edited my answer to match what was asked closely, thx for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access Apache HttpClient javadoc, you have two options :

- Browse the online javadoc : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/ (mentioned as unsatisfying in the question)
- Generate it [by yourself](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#howdoirunjavadoc)

Older versions of HttpClient binary release used to contain a `javadoc` folder.
Ex: http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.2.5-bin.zip contains it.

**Recent version (> 4.3.x) of Apache HttpClient binary release don't include the javadoc anymore**.

Comment: FYI, the 4.3.x releases do not contain the javadoc folder.  The OP was asking about 4.3.1, not 4.2.5.